# OpenGL есть ли альтернатива texture3d?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Написал небольшой воксельный визуализатор и столкнулся с проблемой. Я использую 2d текстуру, в которую особым образом записываю и читаю данные, что отнимает очень много вычислений и на проце и на видеокарте. А 3d текстуры есть в glfw3, но как сказано в glsl, метод texture3d вырезан с версии 140. Как я могу получить удобную альтернативу с минимум вычислительных затрат?
Также проблема в том, что я хочу её очень часто перезаписывать, и лучше всего иметь доступ напрямую, например какой-нибудь одномерный массив с формулой конвертером в 3d форму.

Comment: Второй вопрос "как быстро обновлять текстуру" является оффтопиком по отношению к вопросу про семплер - будет лучше задать его отдельно.

Comment: ¿Какая версия OpenGL и GLSL используются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сама функция никуда не делась, просто преименовалась - суффикс выкинули, тип семплера теперь берется из типа текстуры.

Просто пишите `texture()`

[Оригинал ответа на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17020911/5533854)

[Мануал OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml)

Comment: при использовании texture() выдаёт невозможно вызвать не функцию. Это как-то связано с версией glsl? Или я сделал что-то не так, написав просто что-то в стиле uniform sampler3D map; и texture(map, vec3(0.,0.,0.));

Comment: Покажите весь, код шейдера, в том числе и сообщение об ошибке с указанием строки, на которую ругается. Без этого мы с вами занимаемся угадайкой.

Comment: Спасибо, я нашёл ошибку в том, что у меня оказался рудимент от SFML (а сейчас я переписываю на GLAD/glfw3) в виде uniform sampler2D texture; и то что вы мне написали работает исправно! Буду внимательней

Comment: Если ответ оказался рабочим, не забудьте отметить это, спасибо!